# Actionscript Dictionary: TypeError: Error #1006: getValue is not a function

Tags: apache-flex, dictionary, actionscript, flex3

I have a Flex 3 application where I was using a call to Dictionary.getValue. However, now when compiling I get this error on that call:

> TypeError: Error #1006: getValue is not a function.

Can I be doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide some code that exhibits the behavior you've run into! Unless hackattack's answer is the fix. Question is not very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a getValue method defined in the api ... http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html#methodSummary

try using

```
dictionary[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

the Dictionary object does not have a getValue() function, which is why you get that error. Did you perhaps mean to write valueOf()?